# How to select the network interface on a FlexNet server?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm installing a FlexNet license manager in a server. The server has four network interfaces and I want the license manager to server licences only in one of the interfaces `eth2` (a.k.a e41f13ed30cc from its MAC) but when I start the daemon `ldadmin` it show all the interfaces as hostid's.

```
# ./lmutil hostid
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2012 Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.
The FLEXnet host ID of this machine is ""e41f13ed30ca e41f13ed30cb e41f13ed30cc e41f13ed30cd""
Only use ONE from the list of hostids.
```

And, the log of one of the licenses served, show how it confuse `eth0` with `eth2`:

```
13:36:49 (vtech) Wrong hostid on SERVER line for license file:
13:36:49 (vtech)    licenses/simics/ConsolidatedLicenseFile.lic
13:36:49 (vtech) SERVER line says e41f13ed30cc, hostid is e41f13ed30ca
13:36:49 (vtech) Invalid hostid on SERVER line
```

How to specify that the ldadmin daemon only listen only in one interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the license, It doesn't need to use the hostid of the wanted ethernet, only the first one in order to work with the vendor daemons.